# Bash: How to end printf or echo with a \ and then a new line

Tags: bash, printf, echo

I would like to end printf or echo output with a backslash and move to a new line without having a space at the end of the first line.

For example when I have used the following:

```
printf "This is line one. \ \nThis is line two.
```

The output will have a space after the first \ , and then start the new line. I wondered how I can prevent or remove the end space.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more slashes!

```
printf 'This is line one. \\\nThis is line two.'
```

The first slash escapes the second one, then the third one is part of the newline `\n`.

Importantly, I've also changed the quotes to single. You *could* do it with double quotes but it'd look like this:

```
printf "This is line one. \\\\\nThis is line two."
```

The slashes used to escape other slashes need escaping themselves, which as I'm sure you will agree, is a mess!

Comment: Thanks Tom! I imagined it be something like that, didn't go as far as five \\\\\ - gone with your first example!